# What causes the performance difference between these two implementations of insertion sort?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got two implementations of insertion sort. The first is pretty much a transcription of the example in my java textbook (albeit with a `while` loop instead of the java `for` loop)

```
def insertion_sort(array):
    for i in range(1,len(array)):
        j = i
        while j > 0 and array[j] < array[j-1]:
            array[j],array[j-1] = array[j-1], array[j]
            j=j-1
    return array
```

The second seems to be a more pythonic implementation.

```
def insertion_sort2(array):
    for i in range(1,len(array)):
        for j in range(i-1,-1,-1):
            if array[j+1] < array[j]:
                array[j+1],array[j] = array[j],array[j+1]
            else:
                break
    return array
```

After timing both, it seems the second is much slower (3 to 4 times slower) when the list is already sorted, or very nearly sorted. However, as the number of inversions increase the second implementation seems to gain the upper hand (10-15% faster). I was just wondering if someone could explain what cause of this discrepancy might be. Thanks!

Edit: Here's the function I use to create a random list.

```
def rand_list(length):
    return [random.randint(0,9*length) for _ in range(length)]
```

When I want a list that's partially sorted I just call `list(range(length1)) + rand_list(length2)`.

As for timing how long they take to run I've used both the `%timeit` tool and the difference between two `datetime.now()` calls. They've both given pretty consistent results. Also I just want to emphasize, that I'm creating a new list every time, not sorting an already sorted list.

Comment: Is it Python 2 or 3? if Python 2 try xrange, range preallocates the list in Python2 whereas in Python3 it returns an iterator.

Comment: Python 3, specifically 3.5.2. I've updated the tags to reflect that!

Comment: @totoro The question wasn't how to make this faster, it is to *explain the difference*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In Python 2 the difference could be using range vs not using range.

Comment: I'm not sure yet why your first implementation would be faster for nearly sorted **lists**. However, the other situation is probably explained by while-loops being slower than for-loops in Python.

Comment: what were the test cases you evaluated?

Comment: @totoro Ah, yes, I see what you mean.

Comment: Can't recreate your slowdown. How are you timing these and what input do you supply?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard I've edited my answer to clarify

Comment: Your code can be reproducible if you use a seed, i.e. `random.seed(x)`.  where `x` is some integer.  Consider setting a seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your timings.  For random data or reverse sorted data, *insertion_sort2* is a bit faster than *insertion_sort* on Python3.6.  However, as you noted, *insertion_sort2* is three times slower for data that is already sorted.

The reason for the first case (slightly faster on random or sorted data) is that *range_iterator* objects generate decreasing integers faster (using C-code internally) than manually writing `j=j-1` and `j > 0` which are both pure python steps.  Accordingly, once the for-loop is warmed-up, it runs a bit faster than the while-loop equivalent.

The reason for the second case (much slower on sorted data) is that a while-loop is cheaper than the equivalent for-loop when there are zero iterations.  This is because the while-loop has no set-up costs.  The equivalent for-loop still has to create both a *range* object and a *range_iterator* object before it can figure-out there a no iterations.  Accordingly, while-loops beat for-loops when empty or nearly empty because they avoid set-up costs.